# Can we access programatically iOS System Settings for General/Accessibility/SubTitles & Captioning?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to use subtitles and captioning systems settings from iOS settings app. Is there any way, we can get it programatically.

Answer (score 6):

You can use UIAccessibilityIsClosedCaptioningEnabled() method to know if  iOS Settings-> General -> Accessibility ->  Subtitles & Captioning  -> Closed Captions + SDH is turned ON/OFF

Answer (score 2):

Through AVPlayer's closedCaptionDisplayEnabled property - you can control whether the CC are shown or not, but if the Subtitles and CC switch is switched to ON in General -> Accessibility -> Subtitles and CC - the value of that property is ignored and the CCs are always shown and afaik there's no way to turn it off.

Setting closedCaptionDisplayEnabled to NO does nothing in that case.

Comment: closedCaptionDisplayEnabled
Indicates whether the player uses closed captioning.

@property(nonatomic, getter=isClosedCaptionDisplayEnabled) BOOL closedCaptionDisplayEnabled


Having the same issue. Did anyone find solution?

Comment: Looks like its AVPlayer bug. I was able to disable closed captioning by iterating through each AVPlayerItemTrack and calling setEnabled:NO on it.