# Xcode - Objective C - AVPlayer programmatically - play local video, with standard/system skin

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerlayer

Can anyone help me with code for setting up and playing local videofile, using AVPlayer in Xcode? (using AVPlayerLayer, and AVPlayerViewController)
All done programmatically and with standard/system videoskin?

Regards Henning

Answer (score 19):

```
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:"YOUR URL"];

// create a player view controller
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
controller.player = player;
[player play];
```

hope this help for you.....

Comment: Thanks! Now I can hear the video;) (I dont see it) 

Got this message:
Warning: Attempt to present <AVPlayerViewController: 0x137610df0> on <ViewController: 0x137509580> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

How can I attach the controller to a UIView?

Comment: are you write this code in "viewDidLoad" ?? because of this you got this message just move this code in "viewDidAppear " may this work for you

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new to Objective C..
You are right, if i move the code to viewDidAppear the error goes away, but then no video is playing

Comment: plz add your code...

Answer (score 12):

```
// remote file from server:
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/alf-proeysen/Bakvendtland-MASTER.mp4"];

// create a player view controller
player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

[self addChildViewController:controller];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];

controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(50,50,500,300);
controller.player = player;
controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
player.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled = NO;
[player pause];
[player play];
```

This is all done in `viewDidLoad` and its working fine now. I made a subview to present the player.

The only thing that is not working now is `player.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled = NO;` this is ignored. The video has soft subtitles embedded, and I am able to toggle the subtitles with cc button that is showing. But I am not able to toggle it/control it programmatically?

Comment: ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555936/can-we-access-programatically-ios-system-settings-for-general-accessibility-subt